# Split columns of a dataframe and re-combine them as one column without blanks

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have two dataframes which I want to split based on ";", and recombine the resulting columns into one column with corresponding values.

check the example below. Each number in df2 corresponds to a string in df1 ("aaa" <-> 111, "bbbb" <-> 2222, "ccc" <-> 333, and so on)

```
#The dataframes I have
df1 = c("aaa","bbbb;ccc","dd;eeee;ffff","gg") #1st dataframe
df2 = c("111","2222;333","44;5555;6666","77") #2nd dataframe
df = as.data.frame(cbind(df1,df2)) #combine df1 and df2

#The output I'm trying to achieve
df1_desired = c("aaa","bbbb","ccc","dd","eeee","ffff","gg")
df2_desired = c("111","2222","333","44","5555","6666","77")
df_desired = as.data.frame(cbind(df1_desired,df2_desired)) #this is the format I want
```

I tried the following, but it didn't give me the arrangement I need.

```
split_df1 = str_split_fixed(df$df1, ";", 3)
split_df2 = str_split_fixed(df$df2, ";", 3)
combined_output = cbind(split_df1 ,split_df2 )
```

Would appreciate your suggestions!

**UPDATE**

This solution provided by @snoram worked perfectly for me:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dfd <- df[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ";"), by = seq_len(nrow(df))][, seq_len := NULL]
dfd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dfd <- df[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ";"), by = seq_len(nrow(df))][, seq_len := NULL]
dfd
    df1  df2
1:  aaa  111
2: bbbb 2222
3:  ccc  333
4:   dd   44
5: eeee 5555
6: ffff 6666
7:   gg   77
```

Base R inspired by rar:

```
data.frame(lapply(lapply(df, strsplit, ";"), unlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> data.frame(cbind(unlist(strsplit(df1,";")),unlist(strsplit(df2,";"))))
    X1   X2
1  aaa  111
2 bbbb 2222
3  ccc  333
4   dd   44
5 eeee 5555
6 ffff 6666
7   gg   77
```

First split the text based on ";", then unlist it, cbind both results and convert it into a dataframe.